# For-Each to apply templates XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I posted this question here. It was answered and I'm happy with it. It's just here to reference the XML input and output.

[XML to XML XSLT transformation. MSXML in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885957/xml-to-xml-xslt-transformation-msxml-in-vbscript/59886550#59886550)

Here is my stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:b="urn:myNameSpace" exclude-result-prefixes="b">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/b:MYImportFile">

<MYImportFile>

    <xsl:for-each select="b:SAMPLE">

    <SAMPLE>

        <SAMPLEID>
        <xsl:value-of select="b:SAMPLEID"/>
        </SAMPLEID>

        <NAME1_1>
        <xsl:value-of select="b:LOCATION/b:LOCATIONNAME[text() = 'NAME1']/../b:DATA[1]/b:DATAVALUE"/>
        </NAME1_1>

        <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test="b:LOCATION/b:LOCATIONNAME[text() = 'NAME1']/../b:DATA[2]/b:DATAVALUE">
                <NAME1_2>
                <xsl:value-of select="b:LOCATION/b:LOCATIONNAME[text() = 'NAME1']/../b:DATA[2]/b:DATAVALUE"/>
                </NAME1_2>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <NAME1_2>
                <xsl:value-of select="b:LOCATION/b:LOCATIONNAME[text() = 'NAME1']/../b:DATA[1]/b:DATAVALUE"/>
                </NAME1_2>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


        '''''''''''''''''''there are 100 NAME entires to recieve the 100 locations

    </SAMPLE>

    </xsl:for-each>

</MYImportFile>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What change do I need to make to this to make that `</xsl:for-each>` to a `<xsl:apply-templates>`? Is it an easy change? Or is this going to take an overhaul of the entire stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there a repetitions of the same code, it might be possible to implement them in a template so an overhaul is helpful anyway:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:b="urn:ohLookHEREaNamespacedeclaration"
    exclude-result-prefixes="b"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="b:SAMPLE"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b:SAMPLE">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="b:SAMPLEID | b:LOCATION"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b:LOCATION">
      <xsl:element name="{b:LOCATIONNAME}_1">
          <xsl:value-of select="b:DATA[1]/b:DATAVALUE"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="{b:LOCATIONNAME}_2">
          <xsl:value-of select="b:DATA[2]/b:DATAVALUE | b:DATA[1][current()[not(b:DATA[2])]]/b:DATAVALUE"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRAp3

But in general, instead of doing `<xsl:for-each select="foo"><bar>...</bar></xsl:for-each>` you can of course use `<xsl:apply-templates select="foo"/>` with a matching `<xsl:template match="foo"><bar>...</bar></xsl:template>`, if that is what your main question is about.

Comment: This is actually FANTASTIC. If I could upvote it three times I would. It's short, it's sweet, it's elegant and I understand exactly what it is doing. Let's say I wanted to pick only certain `"{b:LOCATIONNAME}_x"` instead of all 100? Is there a way to do this without creating a separate template for each one that I want? I might have to do a conditional inside a for-each here instead of a template maybe?

Comment: The apply-templates `<xsl:apply-templates select="b:SAMPLEID | b:LOCATION"/>` selects all `b:LOCATION` elements inside each `b:SAMPLE`, you can add a predicate there e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="b:SAMPLEID | b:LOCATION[position() > 2 and position() < 25]"/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="b:SAMPLEID | b:LOCATION[b:READBY = 'foo']"/>`. Another option would be to add an empty template with a condition of the elements you don't want to be output e.g. `<xsl:template match="b:LOCATION[b:READBY != 'foo']"/>`. You might want to ask a new question detaling the "pick only certain".

Comment: I really have to learn more xslt. I have to say again, that’s a beautiful bit of code. I needed to experiment a little to figure out what it all means but I think I’ve got a handle on it and it really is superb. I appreciate it. I’ll see if I can adjust with the additional information you’ve given me here.